# How to access my form values in document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and have a very basic question:

I have this in my HTML

```
Total Cost: <input type="text" name="total" id="total" class="MyInput" />
```

I want to assign a value to this textbox at the program startup, for that I am using `document.ready`, but its not working.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {{
        $("#total").value  = "2";
    });
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have a closing `script` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#total").val('2');
   });
```

Comment: +1 although OP has erroneous extra `{` at the start of the handler function block.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i never know if its polite to update an answer - but just done it !!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You got some jQuery in your javascript... do you mean how to do it in jQuery?

To do this in pure javascript, here's the code:

```
oFormObject = document.forms['myform_id']; //the id of your form
oFormElement = oFormObject.elements["total"];
oFormElement.value=2;
```

And with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
{
    $("#total").val("2");
});
```

Comment: Why not simply use `document.getElementById('total')` in the pure Javascript example?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that was my first thought too, however after I googled to double check my code, I came accross this article: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml which seems to insinuate that document.getElementById() isn't the best way to do it where forms are concerned. Haven't seen it done this way before either but thought I'd better go with what I read rather than my own (rusty) js knowledge.

Comment: now I think about it (and re-read the article) document.getElementById('total') works fine, don't know why I thought it wasn't OK. lol it's a monday

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using JavaScript at all if you just want to set the initial value - and of course you know that value :

```
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="2" class="MyInput" />
```

using the `value=""` parameter in the `input` tag

Comment: He can, but since OP asked to do it in jQuery this doesn't really answer his question. This won't work if OP is getting values from a JSON request on load for example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan totally agree - just wanted to make the point that if he knew the initial value he could set it using HTML....